# Office 365 licences check keeps running and keeps rescheduling

Tags: windows-7, office365

We have quite a few machines that are running "The Software Protection service is starting" from Office software protection platform service.
It enables all the agents and then stop with reschedule.
Then the cycle keeps repeating all the time when computer is on.
Just wondering if anyone else has seen this or possible fix.

Below is a copy of the event.

```
Log Name:      Application
Source:        Office Software Protection Platform Service
Date:          11/6/2018 10:14:48 AM
Event ID:      900
Task Category: None
Level:         Information
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      computername.blah.com
Description:
The Software Protection service is starting.

Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Office Software Protection Platform Service" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="16384">900</EventID>
    <Level>4</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2018-11-06T15:14:48.000000000Z" />
    <EventRecordID>33019</EventRecordID>
    <Channel>Application</Channel>
    <Computer> Computername</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

Then it dies.

```
Log Name:      Application
Source:        Office Software Protection Platform Service
Date:          11/6/2018 10:19:49 AM
Event ID:      903
Task Category: None
Level:         Information
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      computername.blah.com
Description:
The Software Protection service has stopped.

Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Office Software Protection Platform Service" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="16384">903</EventID>
    <Level>0</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2018-11-06T15:19:49.000000000Z" />
    <EventRecordID>33024</EventRecordID>
    <Channel>Application</Channel>
    <Computer>computername.blah.com </Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

Comment: I wouldn't say it "dies" as much as it "shuts down". Event ID 903 for this service is "Shutdown" - the default time for this process to run is 300sec or 5min, which is exactly what happened here. What is your end-goal or concern with this process?

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing is by design, and I would to know why it is annoying you.

Some [information by a Microsoft developer](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f1a1cc72-d835-4d1d-8fa5-0c0d298fe4bc/why-does-office-software-protection-platform-service-continue-to-run-after-completing-a-licensing?forum=officesetupdeployprevious):

> The Office Software Protection Platform service is generally started
>   on demand when a user has started Office, however, there are license
>   types which can start the service otherwise (such as those using a Key
>   Management Server). As for stopping the service, there are several
>   reasons we do not automatically shut down the service by default.
>   These reasons are based on Office's cross OS version compatibility,
>   communications from our users about their Office usage profile,
>   preferences, resource usage profile, and differing ways in utilizing
>   the service between Office and Windows.
>
> That said, while we do not default our service to timing out after
>   inactivity, if this is something your organization values, you have
>   the ability to control this. You may set the following registry key:
>
> Key:
>   `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\OfficeSoftwareProtectionPlatform`
>
> ValueName: `InactivityShutdownDelay`
>
> ValueType: DWORD
>
> ValueData: The number in seconds, that the Office Software Protection
>   Platform will stay running for, after the most recent activity. The
>   windows default for this is 300 seconds.
>
> After setting this key, simply restart the Office Software Protection
>   Platform Service to use the new settings.